# HTML5 + JavaScript (.removeAttribute('value') removes .defaultValue too? Why?)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I came across this oddity creating a routine to clear a form (not reset it, but clear it). I'm not sure why the `.defaultProperty` is "hard linked" to the value attribute, but it most definitely appears to be.

Run this example (in any browser other than IE):

```js
var myText1 = document.getElementById('Text1');
alert('original\ndef = ' + myText1.defaultValue + '\n val = ' + myText1.value);
myText1.value = null;
alert('.value=null\ndef = ' + myText1.defaultValue + '\n val = ' + myText1.value);

var myText2 = document.getElementById('Text2');
alert('original\ndef = ' + myText2.defaultValue + '\n val = ' + myText2.value);
myText2.removeAttribute('value');
alert('.removeAttribute(\'value\')\ndef = ' + myText2.defaultValue + '\n val = ' + myText2.value);

var myRange1 = document.getElementById('Range1');
myRange1.defaultValue = myRange1.value;
alert('original\ndef = ' + myRange1.defaultValue + '\n val = ' + myRange1.value);
myRange1.removeAttribute('value');
alert('.removeAttribute(\'value\')\ndef = ' + myRange1.defaultValue + '\n val = ' + myRange1.value);
```

```html
<form id="frmForm">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Text1</td>
      <td>
        <input id="Text1" type="text" value="1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text2</td>
      <td>
        <input id="Text2" type="text" value="2" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Range1</td>
      <td>
        <input id="Range1" type="range" min="0" max="10" style="width:155px;" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Notice that the Test1 get's a defaultValue based on it's value attribute, and just setting the value property to null leaves the defaultValue property alone.

But for Text2, `.removeAttribute('value')` is used, and both the value and default value are changed.

Now in the case of certain form elements, like type="range", the value property is auto-set if you do not specify a value attribute. In this case it is auto-set to the mid-way point between min and max, which in this case is 5. Please note that this does not set the defaultValue property in any way, so I manually set it. But when `.removeAttribute('value')` is used now only the defaultValue property appears to be changed... most likely due to the fact the range's value is being auto-set back to 5.

These types of inconsistencies require special handling and are a bit of a headache if you are unaware if them, as I was...

In my humble opinion, the value attribute, value property, and defaultValue property should be treated as separate entities after initialization and changing one should not change the other unless specifically implemented by the developer.

Can anyone give me a reason for why these were implemented in this way? Seems like this is a bit of an oversight, and really should be corrected.

Comment: "Can anyone give me a reason for why these were implemented in this way?" — Questions along the lines of "Why did the API designers make this decision?" can generally only be authoritatively answered by those designers and so tend to be a matter of opinion for everyone else. Stackoverflow is geared towards [practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: My question would be, why would you want to remove the value attribute?

Comment: This is the sort of thing that you bring up to the standards committees or to the individual implementations if they're not following the spec or if the spec doesn't define specific behavior.

Comment: We use HTML5 for both online and offline data acquisition. We current have an iOS app that loads a various local HTML5 files, and allows users to enter and save data offline. As such we are saving the actual markup (adding the value attributes if previously undefined), and in certain situations where they load an older previously saved form, and want to clear it out before entering data (this was a client requested feature), the value attributes should essentially be removed.

Comment: Why cannot `.value` be set to empty string `""`? Instead of loading and clearing a previously saved `html` string `form`, could you not load a predefined template of an empty html string `form`?

Comment: @Xorcist: Please ask about the actual problem. If there's some issue with your approach to clearing a form, I'm sure you'll find help.

Comment: I've passed this along to the W3C, I think my post is now more about awareness. It's not that I can't "work around" the issue, but rather that I shouldn't have to do a work around. Their specification (https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-6D6AC0F9) seems to indicate that if the attribute being removed has a default value, that attribute will be re-added with that default value (which doesn't seem to be the case).

Comment: `.defaultValue` *is* the `value` attribute. They are one and the same. Removing one will remove the other.

Comment: `.defaultValue` is not exactly the `value` attribute. But they are said to [*reflect*](http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#dom-htmlinputelement-defaultvalue) one another. [Reflection](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#reflection) has a precise definition that describes how getting and setting each affects the other, including how to map data types between two.